# firebase cloud messaging push notification

Tags: python, android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase cloud messaging for push notification
when I publish my notification using python and firebase cloud messaging panel notification doesn't appear in notification bar
what things I need to add to my project

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please include your Python code in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about the python app just follow the documentation provided in the Android Offical documentation here

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

Also, make sure you have added FCM properly inside the android app and also that you have added Key to the python code from Firebase Console.